# How do you go from transit times to Earth-Sun distance?

Tags: observational-astronomy, distances, mathematics, astronomical-unit

In the early 18th century, [Halley described a method](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/%7Epogge/Ast161/Unit4/venussun.html) to determine the value of the astronomical unit by observing a transit of Venus from multiple locations on Earth. How do you go from the transit time at two different locations to the distance between the Sun and the Earth? I found many descriptions in rather vague terms of this method, but what is the math behind it?

Comment: Different question, but somewhat related: [Before the 1761 transit, what was our best estimate of the distance to the Sun?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39233/7982)

Answer (score 1):

We know, precisely, the ratio between the Earth-Venus and Venus-Sun distances. Kepler's laws give us this.

We know, in terms of apparent size in the sky, the precise size of the Sun in degrees - just by looking at it.

Placing Venus between the Sun and the Earth, we can look at it from one point in the Earth (call it $N$) and see Venus against the Sun at a point I'll call $n$. Repeating from another place (call it $S$) at a different latitude, we get another point, $s$. If we know how far apart these two points are in the sky, we can use the *relative* distance of Venus to tell us the angle, at Venus, of the lines $N$-Venus-$n$ and $S$-Venus-$s$. Since we know the distance in kilometres between $N$ and $S$, that means we can solve the triangle and get the distance in kilometres between Venus and $N$ or $S$. (I am tacitly omitting a few steps here, such as the fact that the "distance" between $N$ and $S$ is a north-south distance and not a great-circle distance along the surface of the Earth). Having the distance between Venus and $N$ or $S$, we can multiply that up (since we know the ratio accurately) to the distance between the Sun and $N$ or $S$.

So it remains to find the distance in the sky between $n$ and $s$. Direct measurement cannot be done accurately enough. Accordingly we use *transit time* as a proxy. A line going through the middle of the Sun is longer than a line slicing across the top or bottom of it. So transit time tells us how far north or south of the Sun's diameter the point $s$ or $n$ is travelling.

Three transit times are actually needed, not two. To see this, suppose that the times for $s$ and $n$ were equal. All we would then know, strictly speaking, is that they were symmetrically disposed about the diameter - not how far north or south of the diameter they were. But since we know how fast Venus travels across the face of the Sun we can *calculate* the duration of a hypothetical transit along the diameter, and that figure can then be combined with just two actual observations.

To summarise:

- Transit durations give latitudes on the Sun's disc.
- Latitudes on the Sun's disc give an angular distance between two transit points.
  – The ratio of orbit sizes transforms this into the angle of a long thin triangle based at Venus and joining the two observation points on the Earth.
  – Trigonometry gives the Venus-Earth distance in terrestrial units.
  – The ratio of orbit sizes, again, gives the Sun-Earth distance in terrestrial units.

Comment: How do you go from transit durations to latitudes?